# Pass compiled angular template to HereMaps API

Tags: javascript, html, angular, compilation

I am using HereMaps in my Angular App which is working fine so far. My current problem is, that the H.ui.InfoBubble component only accepts plain html and no angular template.

```
 let bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(
      { lat: data.ride.position.latitude, lng: data.ride.position.longitude },
      // this is currently unfortunately not working, the content gets copied 1:1
      { content: '<app-my-angular-component></app-my-angular-component>'}
```

I thought about compiling the template at lifetime but did not succedded here.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing string with HTML, you can pass an DOM tree node. So you could take and components `nativeElement` and pass it to the function. You could [create the component dynamically](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), then remove it from the DOM tree and finally, pass it to the bubble.

*I have little experience doing this, so I'm unable to provide example*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint @kvetis!

Those were the necessary steps to achieve the result:

```
// 1. Add your bubble component to entryComponents
...
entryComponents: [BubbleComponent]
...

// 2. Add these includes
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, ViewContainerRef,    
    ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';

// 3. Init your Viewchild
@ViewChild("map", { static:false, read: ViewContainerRef }) mapContainer: 
    ViewContainerRef

// 4. Create the "factory" on your bubbleComponent in ngOnInit
this.factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BubbleComponent);

// 5. Create your component dynamically and it to your Dommarker
let componentRef = this.mapContainer.createComponent(this.factory);
let bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(
{ lat: data.ride.position.latitude, lng: data.ride.position.longitude },
   // The FO property holds the province name.
   {
      content: componentRef.location.nativeElement
});

// 6. Don't forget to destroy your component refs on destroy
```

More information can be found [here](https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d)